# EJB application deploying failed in GlassFish

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I have added 2 projects as class libraries to my ejb project. These cliass library projects have only SE Java classes which are for domains and some other value objects. I use GlassFish 3 and IDE is Netbeans 7.0.1. The task 'Clean & Builds' of all class library projects, ejb project and the web project( which JSPs and servlets exist in) are successful and this clean & Build is done by the IDE. But ejb project cannot be deployed as it gives exceptions(`java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:`) saying the class libraries are not found.

I removed and added those libraries many times. But always same error. When I don't use those class libraries and don't use them, then the ejb app can be deployed. As I think, the problem is, the IDE cannot deploy the ejb app if any other projects has been imported and added to the ejb app.(I don't know exactly, but I guess).

I m new to ejb .Please let me know how to deploy this ejb app together with  other projects. Thanks in advance
Here is the error.

```
SEVERE: DPL8008: method/class loading failure : (EjbDescriptor.getBusinessMethodDescriptors()) 
 method/class name - {1}
SEVERE: Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer load method
java.lang.RuntimeException: EJB Container initialization error
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:290)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:186)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:257)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:382)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1064)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1244)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1232)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:209)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:238)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/app/model/User
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.factory.EJBSecurityManagerFactory.createManager(EJBSecurityManagerFactory.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:229)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/app/model/User
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.EjbDescriptor.getLocalRemoteBusinessMethodDescriptors(EjbDescriptor.java:2302)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.EjbDescriptor.getBusinessMethodDescriptors(EjbDescriptor.java:2312)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.EjbDescriptor.getMethodDescriptors(EjbDescriptor.java:2217)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.convertEJBMethodPermissions(EJBSecurityManager.java:546)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.loadPolicyConfiguration(EJBSecurityManager.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.initialize(EJBSecurityManager.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.<init>(EJBSecurityManager.java:190)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.factory.EJBSecurityManagerFactory.createManager(EJBSecurityManagerFactory.java:209)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/app/model/User
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2547)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1410)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.EjbDescriptor.addAllInterfaceMethodsIn(EjbDescriptor.java:2327)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.EjbDescriptor.getLocalRemoteBusinessMethodDescriptors(EjbDescriptor.java:2280)
    ... 40 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to deploy your external lib within your war (e.g. in `WEB-INF/lib`) or place it somehow in the containers classpath (not preferred). How to do this depends on your container and your buildtool/ide.

Comment: Thanks. There are few concerns. Putting the modules into a folder inside `WEB-INF` can be problem to me as the modules will have to be include every time when any changes are done to the particular project. The other thing is; I don't the possibility of putting jar s into the classpath if the app is deployed in a commercial hosting server(they won't let us put our own libs into their classpath).